# Creating a ToolBox component with design-time support using a UserControl

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, components, design-time

I have a UserControl for Windows Forms. How can I convert it to a component? What I want to do is, to add it to the VS toolbox, add it to form with drag and drop at design-time and change its Location and Dock properties using the Properties window. What should I look for to do this?

I've created something similar before but it was a Component class. I can add it to the VS toolbox, add it to the form with drag and drop and change its custom properties using the Properties window but since it's a component it shows on bottom component area and has no design-time support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UserControl` **is** a `Component`. You don't have to do anything extra to make it so.

If you create a new `UserControl` within VS, it will automatically have the behavior you are seeking: drag from toolbox onto form, change its properties through the Properties panel.

This code creates functioning control that shows itself in the toolbox, and allows its properties to be changed.

```
public class TestUserControl : UserControl
{
    public TestUserControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoEllipsis = true;
        this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 51);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "This is a test user control";
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // TestUserControl
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "TestUserControl";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 51);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

Maybe you could add your functionality to this class and see if it works then.